# No padding or margin is working on the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding, margin

No padding or margin is working on the right side and I'm not sure if the problem is with the unit `vw` but changing it didn't work

I'm hoping if you can try the code yourself and see if you can solve it for me being able to have padding or a margin on the right side of the page.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 10px;
}

.logo-name-logo {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flexitem {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 200px;
}

.logo-1 {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.name {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.logo-2 {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Meshal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo-name-logo">
      <div class="flexitem logo-1"></div>
      <div class="flexitem name"></div>
      <div class="flexitem logo-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-title"></div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you want this to look like but my best guess is something like the below snippet. I don't think you need the `width: 100vw` or `width: 100%` rules. Block elements are going to take the full horizontal width naturally and forcing them to 100% in this case is probably causing your issue.

Also, if your goal is to distribute flex items equally, please note the `flex: 1 1 auto` rules instead of setting a static pixel width.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 10px;
}

.logo-name-logo {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flexitem {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.logo-1 {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.name {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.logo-2 {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Meshal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo-name-logo">
      <div class="flexitem logo-1"></div>
      <div class="flexitem name"></div>
      <div class="flexitem logo-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="job-title"></div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;   /* Added to manage the box size automatically*/
}

.logo-name-logo {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin: 10px; */
}

.flexitem {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 200px;
}

.logo-1 {
    min-height: 100px;

}

.name {
    min-height: 100px;

}

.logo-2 {
    min-height: 100px;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try with important in th css !
Like this :
margin : 10px important;